# Remove characters from JSON

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I try to parse some json with logstash, currently the file which I like to enter has the following structure (simplified):

```
-4: {"audit":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}}
-4: {"audit":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}}
```

Therefore I need to remove the -4: prefix in order to proper parse the file using json. Unfortunately I can not use the json codec for the input plugin, because it is not in proper json format. Therefore my requirements for the pipeline are:

1. Remove the -4: prefix
2. Code the event to json
3. Do proper mutation

I have tried with the following pipeline, which gives me a parse error:

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 5001
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "^-\d:."
      what => previous
    }
    #codec => json_lines
    type => "raw_input"
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "raw_input" {
    mutate {
      gsub => ["message", "^-\d:.", ""]
    }
  }

  json {
    source => "message"
  }

  mutate {
    convert => { "[audit][sequenceNumber]" => "integer" }
    add_field => { "test" => "%{[audit][sequenceNumber]}"}
  }
}

output {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/logstash/debug-output.log"
    codec => line { format => "%{message}" }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this with logstash? Any suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [`dissect` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-dissect.html)

```
if [type] == "raw_input" {
  dissect {
    mapping => {
      "message" => "-%{num}: %{msg}"
    }
  }
}

json {
  source => "msg"
}
```